# Spring test listener: how to know if my test failed?

Tags: java, spring, testng, spring-test

I have a number of very complex integration tests written with use of Spring Test framework. What I would like to do is to fetch last n lines from server log file in case test is failed.

For this purposes I created test:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({LogFetchingTestListener.class})  
public MyComplexTestClass extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Test
    public void myComplexTest() {
        // Here goes the test logic...
    }
}
```

and test listener:

```
public class LogFetchingTestListener extends ABstractTestExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(TestContext context) {
        // Use some spring beans to get entities to connect to servers
    }
}
```

Everything is fine but I was unable to find properties in `TestContext` or somewhere else which will let me know if my test has failed or not.

It is pretty critical as I have a big number of tests and it is completely senseless to fetch logs for test cases that were run successfully.

Do Spring provide this information in test listeners? If no, is there any workarounds for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend overriding `afterTestMethod(TestContext)` instead of `afterTestExecution(TestContext)`, since the former will be executed after `@AfterMethod` lifecycle methods in the test class.

To obtain the exception (i.e., the cause of a failed test), you just need to access `testContext.getTestException()`.

Comment: Sam, thank you for pointing the method I should override! Am I getting this right, that test is always not null for failed test cases? Is it possible that succeed test case will have this field populated as well, for example when I expect this exception and validate it was thrown?

Comment: I guess it depends on the testing framework you're using and how/where you "expect this exception and validate it was thrown".

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this in Junit5 and Spring.

I'm considering that you either need to create a report like Extent/Allure or simply log the info/error messages whenever a test is failed/skipped/passed etc.

You need to implement the TestWatcher api extention from Junit5 instead of TestExecutionListener.

Below is an example -

Step 1: Create an extension class "TestWatcherExtention" implementing TestWatcher methods.

```
public class TestWatcherExtention implements TestWatcher {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestResultNotifierExtension.class);

    private List<TestResultStatus> testResultsStatus = new ArrayList<>();

    private enum TestResultStatus {
        SUCCESSFUL, ABORTED, FAILED, DISABLED;
    }

  @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
        logger.info("Test Failed for test {}: ", context.getDisplayName());

        testResultsStatus.add(TestResultStatus.FAILED);
        ExtentTestReportManager.getTest().log(Status.FAIL, "Test Failed");
    }

//similarly override methods for test Passed, Skipped etc.

}
```

Step 2: Add the above implementation using @ExtendWith annotation from Junit5.

```
@SpringbootTest
@ExtendWith(TestWatcherExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {

//my junit5 tests

}
```

Now you're good to go